# Chi squared distribution $N(0,\frac{1}{2})$ asymptotically distributed

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

How can one proof the following:

Let $S_n$ be $\chi_n^2$-distributed. Then $\sqrt{S_n}-\sqrt{n}$ is asymptotically $N(0,\frac{1}{2})$ distributed, i.e. $\sqrt{S_n}-\sqrt{n}$ ~. $N(0,\frac{1}{2})$.

I wanted to use the follwing result: If $\sqrt{n}(T_n-n)$ ~. $N(0, \sigma^2)$, then for a differentiable function $h$ with $h(\mu) \neq 0$ we get

$\sqrt{n}(h(T_n)-h(\mu))$ ~. $N(0,\sigma^2 h'(\mu)^2),$

but I don't know how to start. Can someone give me  hint or help me?

Comment: would it help that $S_n$ ~$ Gamma(n/2,1/2)$? That can be proved using the mgf of the gamma distribution after having found that the square of a standard normal is gamma.

Answer (score 0):

We have $$f_{S_n}(x) = \frac{x^{n/2-1} e^{-x/2}}{2^{n/2} \Gamma(n/2)}, \quad x > 0.$$  Thus, $Y = \sqrt{S_n} - \sqrt{n}$ has density $$f_Y(y) = f_{S_n}((y+\sqrt{n})^2) 2(y+\sqrt{n}) = \frac{(y+\sqrt{n})^{n-1} e^{-(y+\sqrt{n})^2/2}}{2^{n/2-1} \Gamma(n/2)}, \quad y > -\sqrt{n}.$$  Using Stirling's approximation for $$\Gamma(n/2) \sim \sqrt{\pi} \sqrt{n - 1/2} \left(\frac{n/2-1}{e}\right)^{n/2-1} + O(1/n)$$ and taking the logarithm, we get for $n > 2$ $$\log (\sqrt{\pi} f_Y(y)) \approx \frac{n-1}{2} \log \frac{(y + \sqrt{n})^2}{n-2} - \frac{y^2}{2} - y \sqrt{n} -1,$$ the limit of which as $n \to \infty$ is $-y^2$, by a straightforward calculation (e.g. L'Hopital's rule).  Therefore, as $n \to \infty$ we have $$f_Y(y) \to e^{-y^2}/\sqrt{\pi},$$ which is normal with mean $0$ and variance $1/2$.

Comment: Just a question: Shouldnt there be $\Gamma(\frac{n}{2}$ ~ $ \sqrt{\pi} \sqrt{\frac{n}{2} - 1} ( \frac{\frac{n}{2}-1}{e})^(\frac{n}{2}-1)$? And how do you get the next approximation for the $\log$?